# Skip Optional Header in CSV file with SuperCSV

Tags: java, csv, import, supercsv

I have a system where users can import data through csv files.
The file is parsed to POJOs using SuperCSV.

I want to be able to manage these files with or without the header row.

`CsvBeanReader.getHeader(true)` will extract the first row, but if it is not a header then that row won't be parsed by the BeanReader.

Is there an easy way of detecting the header without losing the first line of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

By wrapping the provided `Reader` using a `BufferedReader` I could mark the beginning, read the first line, and then do `reader.reset()` if it's not the header.

Answer (score 1):

The best idea to skip header from super csv while reading the values from file:-

//dont write this line beanReader.getHeader(true)

// before reading the values pass headers array that u have declared like headers = {column1},{column2}

//then use below lines, which exclude the header

beanReader.read(type, headers, processors))

Above steps help us to read the csv file which was saved without header.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to just read the file twice (check for expected headers on the first pass - you only need to read the first line, and read with/without header on the second pass).